# Python3 - Trying to import module from other folder with sys not working. How to fix it?

Tags: python

I'm using Python3 on Windows. I have the following file structure:

[image]

This is the folder path when I copy it from windows:

```
D:\5 - Coding\Back-end\CreateGames\kato_utils
```

I'm trying to import the full module:

```
kato_utils.py
```

into:

```
main.py
```

But it does not work.
Here are the path I tried in my main.py but none works:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "D:/5 - Coding/Back-end/CreateGames/kato_utils")
# sys.path.insert(1, "D:\5 - Coding\Back-end\CreateGames\kato_utils")
# sys.path.insert(1, "D:\\5 - Coding\\Back-end\\CreateGames\\kato_utils")
import kato_utils
from kato_utils import kato_utils
```

How to import kato_utils.py or any of his functions into my main.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put an `__init__.py` file inside the kato_utils folder you wouldn't have to worry about using the `sys.path` you could just use

```
from kato_utils import kato_utils
```

As it stands now this:

```
import kato_utils
```

should work and the second from

```
kato_utils ....
```

is unnecessary